# soapUI version issue: DispatchException: Missing operation for soapAction

Tags: soap, soapui

My code was earlier working with soapUi2.5.
but when I started working with soapUI2.5.1, I started getting this error.

com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Missing operation for soapAction [http://SEWSI.ServiceContracts/2008/09/ReceiveSubscription] and body element [{http://SEWSI.ServiceContracts/2008/09}ReceiveSubscriptionRequest] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]

I would appreciate if some can explain me what this signifies.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found your solution - albeit a year later!

Your mock service may have problems in requiring a Soap Action

- In SoapUI select your mock service
- In it's property window change 'Require SOAP Action' to false

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I bet it means that soapUI thinks it's telling the truth. It thinks there should be an operation for that combination, but it can't find one. Did you maybe update the WSDL but not the MockService? In this case, the difference in soapUI version would be a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with soapUI, with the response coming 1st time and then for a subsequent request, it was getting blank.
It seems like a library issue.

Use https://github.com/eveoh/weblogic-soapui-mock-ear to wrap the war into the ear.
This has resolved an issue for me. I have used Weblogic 12c.